# RLlib: Understanding how many workers and trainers are used for a specific algorithm

Tags: ray

I am currently trying to wrap my mind arround how RLlib works with different algorithms. Let me try to explain how I understand things and it would be great if someone of you could give some feedback about it.

If I use a simple DQN algorithm and create a single trial like this:

```
trial = run_experiments({
    custom_params["exp_tag"]: {
        "run": DQN,
        "env": gym_name,
        "config": {
            **config
        },
        "num_samples": 1
    },
})
```

where I use some plain syncronous DQN configurations with num_workers=10 and num_gpus=3. Then in fact the trial will not make use of the 10 workers and probably won't use all GPUs for the learner, because the algorithm is designed for the interaction between *one* learner and *one* worker, right?

Now, when I use A3C, things look different, because here one has asynchronous workers and learners, so the algorithm will make use of as many resources as possible dependent on if the learner or the worker is actually the bottleneck.

Now in the realm of High-throughput architectures it looks similar. When I use e.g. Ape-X, then all worker resources will be used for the policy evaluation and creating prioritized experience replay while only one learner is used.

As said before, I would be glad if someone would comment and correct me on my understanding presented above.

BR, Vallout